# Profiling Xcode tests from the command line

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, profiling, xcode-instruments

I've written unit tests in Xcode, using [XCTest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/01-introduction.html), and they are running great from Xcode. Besides the GUI environment, I also have a makefile that automates some processes from the command line. These include building, testing, cleaning, analyzing, and so on. The rationale for this is including the scripts in a build pipeline, mostly for nightly builds. With that we get builds, performance reports, memory leaks, and so on, fresh in the morning.

I'd also like to [profile](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeProfile.html) from the [command line](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/Instruments_help_articles/Articles/ProfilingwiththeinstrumentsCommand-lineTool.html), using [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/). Here's how I'm doing it:

```
instruments -t "Allocations" -D build/hul.trace hul.xcodeproj
```

I get the following output:

```
Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Unable to find actual binary to posix_spawn for path: hul.xcodeproj
```

Is this related with the project being a static library? I'd like the tool to write the results to a file, so that I can consult in the next day, or even automate some processing, such as using pattern matching. Has anyone done something like this before using Instruments?

Edit: This seems to be doing *something*:

```
sudo instruments -v -t "Time Profiler" "build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hulTests.xctest/" -w "iPhone SE"
```

However, then I get the following dialog:

[image]

I just don't know what the *appropriate action* is...

Edit: One thing was wrong. According to the docs:

```
 -w [hardware device, or simulator name]
          The name or identifier of the hardware device or simulator to target. Should be specified first
```

So the previous line changes to:

```
instruments  -w "iPhone SE" -v -t "Time Profiler" "build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hulTests.xctest/"
```

Also, besides "iPhone SE" I'm using an actual device identifier, and I read somewhere that you're not supposed to use `sudo`. Indeed this helped! I noticed that the results for `instruments -s devices` and `sudo instruments -s devices` is actually different. So now I'm getting a different error:

```
Instruments : Instruments Accepted Command
Instruments : Preparing To Start Trace
Instruments : Starting Instrument(s)
Instruments : Stopping Instrument(s)
Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.hypelabs.test was denied.
make: *** [profile] Error 253
```

I googled around and this seems to indicate signing errors, but does that make sense if I'm running unit tests? That is, I'm writing a static library, so there's not even a .app file to sign.